# Problem with the post format ( array) ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, fetch

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

in the following code I map a table, and I post all of this in a database 
everything works fine. the only problem and the format in which I receive it.

```
{
    "id": 136,
    "items": "[{\"title\":\"Campus (Pinte)\",\"quantity\":2}]",    
}
```

I would rather recover it in another format than in arrays. here is my code:

```js
postbackend = () => {
  const newItems = this.props.items.map(item => {
    const { title, quantity } = item;
    return {
      title,
      quantity
    };
  });
  const config = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ ...this.state, items: newItems })
  };
  const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";
  fetch(url, config)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      if (res.error) {
        alert(res.error);
        this.props.history.replace("/OrderSummaryPaymentFalseScreen"); // Your Error Page
      } else {
        alert(`film ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
        this.props.history.push("/OderSummaryScreen"); // Your Success Page
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
      this.props.history.replace("/OrderSummaryPaymentFalseScreen"); // Your Error Page
    })
    .finally(() =>
      this.setState({
        redirect: true
      })
    );
};
```

Do you have an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: You're not getting it in arrays. You get a response that has an array of `items`, and each item is a normal JSON encoded object. Writing code that turns that into "what you need" takes a few lines of code at most, so rather than trying to change what you get, just roll with it and _turn it into_ what you want? Write a function that does that transformation, and now you only need that code in once place.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans hi , thx for help , what you could be more precise ? do you have ex ?  or what is the " function" for that ? thx Neff

Comment: your code already pretty much has this. You're not showing what's in `this.props.items`, and you not saying what the actual _problem_ is (does the POST not work? does your `newItems()` function not work? What doesn't actually work here?), so there's not much else to say.  Also, never use `alert()`. Just use `console.log` in the same way you're using `console.error` already.